# Asynchronous REST webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

I have a problem with my REST webservice I want to run asynchronously. The example shows, what I want to do. The main problem is that the web service is not accepting a new request until the old finished. I am using Wildfly 10 as my application server and its RESTeasy implementation.

**WebApplication.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class WebApplication extends Application
{
    public WebApplication ()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

**TestService.java**

```
@Path("test")
public class TestService
{
    @Inject
    private TestBean bean;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getDateTime(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response)
    {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> response.resume(bean.getResult()))
                .exceptionally((ex) -> (response.resume(ex)));
    }
}
```

**TestBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean
{
    public TestTO getResult()
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Entering REST service");

        for (long l = 0; l < Long.MAX_VALUE; l++)
        {
            // just for simulating a veeeery heavy operation
        }
        return new TestTO();
    }
}
```

The *TestTO* is just a simple POJO, so nothing special in there. I cant imagine whats wrong. I searched in google to have a look at different approaches but nothing worked. Something I tried, too, just for testing:

I placed the loop after the *response.resume()* call and a new request was accepted without leaving the previous one (used simple logging statements to debug).

So... What is blocking a second request? I really dont get it, or am I missing something ridiculous?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make TestBean `@RequestScoped`. Only one thread can access an EJB instance at a time.

Comment: TestBean is `@Stateless` annotated, so the container will create a new instance for every request (if we ignore pool size and reusage)? So every thread has its own instance... correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There's no reason to think that will happen; I believe it defaults to @Dependent and you're injecting it into a JAX-RS service which is effectively a singleton

Comment: I added a `@PostConstruct` method to the bean with a simple Log statement. And in the logfile I can see a related message for every request I made. So I guess, a new instance is created every time. If I change the bean to be a `@Singleton` only one log record at startup occurs (apperently).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

I didn't write a client appliation which performs the requests simultaneous, instead I used Firefox to quickly see the output. I opened 2 tabs and called the URL for the webservice. Later I did exactly the same with Microsoft Edge and ... its working! The exmaple is working to 100%.

I dont know why... maybe because Edge is spawning a complete new process per tab and Firefoy doesnt? Never mind, next time I use SoupUI to test webservices.

I am sorry for the stupid question. If I had worked correctly, I had seen the issue.